# how to know the mouse click position is in element or out of element

Tags: typescript

I want to close the popup window if user click the mouse outside the window in google chrome extension. But how to know the user current mouse click in the popup window of out of the popup window? I could capture the click event in google chrome extension script like this:

```
document.addEventListener(TransGlobal.MOUSE_CLICK, mouseClick);
```

and do something in the mouseClick function:

```
export async function mouseClick(e: MouseEvent) {
  if( click out of the popup window){
    // close popup window
  }
}
```

what is the way do to this logic? This is the popup:

```
<div id="pop-container">
      <div id="translate-panel">
        <div class="header">
          <div class="left"></div>
          <div class="right">
            <button type="button" title="Close" @click="closePopWindow">
              <span icon="cross">
                <svg data-icon="cross" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                  <path d="M9.41 8l3.29-3.29c.19-.18.3-.43.3-.71a1.003 1.003 0 00-1.71-.71L8 6.59l-3.29-3.3a1.003 1.003 0 00-1.42 1.42L6.59 8 3.3 11.29c-.19.18-.3.43-.3.71a1.003 1.003 0 001.71.71L8 9.41l3.29 3.29c.18.19.43.3.71.3a1.003 1.003 0 00.71-1.71L9.41 8z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
                </svg>
              </span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="body">
          <div id="reddwarf-translate-result"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what kind of `popup window` is it?  Is it a `focusable` element? Will it be possible for you to include an example html template?

Comment: I have added the popup window.@NalinRanjan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The idea is to intercept the click, obtain the clicked element, and traverse through it's parents to see if any of them is the popup.*

Try following....

```
document.onclick = processDocumentClick;

function processDocumentClick(clickEvent: MouseEvent) {

  let clickTarget: HTMLElement | null = clickEvent.target as HTMLElement;
  let isClicked = isPopupClicked(clickTarget);
  console.log(isClicked ? 'Popup Clicked' : 'Click Outside Popup');

  function isPopupClicked(clickTarget: HTMLElement): boolean {
    const popupContainer = document.querySelector('#pop-container') as HTMLDivElement;
    return isAncestorOf(popupContainer, clickTarget);
  }

  function isAncestorOf(parentElement: HTMLElement, childElement: HTMLElement) {
    let traversalElement: HTMLElement | null = childElement;

    let isParent = false;

    if (traversalElement) {
      while (traversalElement) {
        if (traversalElement === parentElement) {
          isParent = true;
          break;
        } else {
          traversalElement = traversalElement.parentElement;
        }
      }
    }
    return isParent;
  }
}
```

---

### Here is an illustration. Run the code

```js
document.onclick = processDocumentClick;

function processDocumentClick(clickEvent) {

  let clickTarget = clickEvent.target;
  let isClicked = isPopupClicked(clickTarget);
  console.log(isClicked ? 'Popup Clicked' : 'Click Outside Popup');

  function isPopupClicked(clickTarget) {
    const popupContainer = document.querySelector('#pop-container');
    return isAncestorOf(popupContainer, clickTarget);
  }

  function isAncestorOf(parentElement, childElement) {
    let traversalElement = childElement;
    let isParent = false;
    if (traversalElement) {
      while (traversalElement) {
        if (traversalElement === parentElement) {
          isParent = true;
          break;
        } else {
          traversalElement = traversalElement.parentElement;
        }
      }
    }
    return isParent;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="area-which-is-not-popup" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: blue; margin: 10px">

  </div>
  <div id="pop-container" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 3px; background-color: yellow">
    <div id="translate-panel">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="right">
          <button type="button" title="Close" @click="closePopWindow">
              <span icon="cross">
                <svg data-icon="cross" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                  <path d="M9.41 8l3.29-3.29c.19-.18.3-.43.3-.71a1.003 1.003 0 00-1.71-.71L8 6.59l-3.29-3.3a1.003 1.003 0 00-1.42 1.42L6.59 8 3.3 11.29c-.19.18-.3.43-.3.71a1.003 1.003 0 001.71.71L8 9.41l3.29 3.29c.18.19.43.3.71.3a1.003 1.003 0 00.71-1.71L9.41 8z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
                </svg>
              </span>
            </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="body">
        <div id="reddwarf-translate-result" style="color: red">POPUP AREA</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

---

---

On Stackoverflow, [WYSIWYG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) => ***`WHAT YOU SHOW IS WHAT YOU GET`***